# curl send post request for Flask python app failed

Tags: curl, flask

The following is my Flask app code,which is very basic:

```
from models import Base, User
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, url_for, abort
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from flask import Flask

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///users.db')

Base.metadata.bind = engine
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/users', methods = ['POST'])
def new_user():
    username = request.json.get('username')
    password = request.json.get('password')
    print username
    print password



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000)
```

and use `curl` to send HTTP POST request in command line as following:
`curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"abc","password":"123"}' http://localhost:5000/api/users`

but get error of `400 BAD REQUEST`

BTW, I run this app in windows cmd.

any help will be welcomed, thanks in advance.

EDIT:
after debugging, after the issue comes from

```
username = request.json.get('username')
password = request.json.get('password')
```

these two command. If comment out the above two lines, the curl request can success. But still don't know the reason

[image]

Comment: Could you append the full backtrace?  Just the `400 bad request` may not provide enough information.

Comment: add a picture to show the message. But no backtrace information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view function needs to return a response. If you want to return an empty response body, add this:

```
return ('',201)
```

to the end of `new_user()`

Comment: yes, I miss the return part in my post. But add it in my code, still the same issue. That's not the reason

Answer (score 2):

I have also encountered this issue before. If using curl in windows cmd you may need to use double quotes, and escape those quotes in your JSON.

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d 
"{\"username\":\"abc\",\"password\":\"123\"}" http://localhost:5000/api/users
```

Comment: This worked for me, using curl on windows. Alternatively, one can use an app for testing APIs such as Postman to format and send requests